# Is this possible in SQL?

Tags: sql, date

I have Table A and Table B

```
**Table A** 
Claim_ID PK

**Table B** 
Claim_State_ID
Claim_ID FK
Claim State
Claim_State_Start_Date
Claim_State_End_Date
```

Table A can have many Table B

Claim State can have three values: Terminated, Submitted and Payment Complete.

Is it possible for me to do a select on Table A.Claim_ID where the Claim State is Terminated but the previous state must be Payment complete. I would do this by checking the Start and End Dates.

Essentially, I need to only select the Claims where the state is terminated but the state sometime before this is Terminated and not submitted.

I don't have data at the moment but this would be my logical attempt.

```
Select COUNT (Claim_ID) from TableA JOIN TableB On TableA.Claim_ID=TableB.Claim_ID Where TableB.Claim_State ="Terminated" and Claim_State_End_Date
```

The statement is cut short here as I need to compare the date to the date of Send to Payment state.

Is this even possible?

Comment: Which SQL variation are you using (ie MS SQL 2008, MySQL, oracle)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forgive the archaic join syntax. I prefer it, for some reason...

I think you're asking "find all claims where there's a record showing it's terminated, and another record showing it's paid, and the termination date is greater than the paid date."

```
select a.claim_ID
from   TableA a, 
       TableB term, 
       TableB paid
where  a.claim_id  =  term.claim_id
and    a.claim_id  =  paid.claim_id
and    term.Claim State  = 'TERMINATED'
and    paid.Claim State  = 'PAID'
and    term.Claim_State_Start_Date >= paid.Claim_State_Start_Date
```

Comment: This looks like it will work, I won't be able to test it yet but I thank you for your answer. I didn't know you could do this in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

This will not be possible unless you explicitly store somewhere which claims have ever been payment complete. You will have to add at least a flag or a whole new table for that.

Answer (score 0):

row_number and Common Table Expressions are your friend.

```
WITH cte AS
(
   select
          Claim_Id,
          Claim_State,
          Row_Number() over (Partition by Claim_Id order by Claim_State_Start_Date) as row
   from
   Table_B
)
select a.Claim_ID
from cte a inner join cte b on a.Claim_Id = b.Claim_Id and a.row = b.row + 1

where a.Claim_State = 'Terminated' and b.Claim_State = 'Paid';
```

This will check that the immediately preceeding state is 'Paid' to have any preceding state 'Paid' change the query to `select distinct` and the row test to `a.row > b.row`